# Potential at a certain point inside a non-uniform hollow conducting sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, coulombs-law

> A thin metallic spherical shell contains a charge $Q$ over it. A point charge $+q$ is placed is placed inside the shell at point $T$ separated from the center by a distance $a$ ( $a < R$ ). Another point charge $+q_1$ is placed outside the shell at a distance $b$ from center. Find the potential at the center of the metallic spherical shell due to all the charges in space.

The answer that is given in the book is $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{q}{a}+\frac{Q}{R}+\frac{q_1}{b}\right]. $The answer given assumes uniform distribution of the charges both inside and outside the sphere. My teacher told that the distribution of charges on the outer surface is indeed independent of the charge distribution of the inner surface (I am having a hard time understanding why though, the induced field needs to cancel both the fields by $+q$ and $+q_1$, and since they are at some arbitrary distance away, how can they be uniform?) , so I can make out that the potential on the surface of the metallic sphere is $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\cdot\frac{Q+q}{R}$. But how to proceed? Since the point charge $+q$ is not located at the center of the metallic sphere, should not electric field inside the cavity be non-uniform? How can one go about finding the potential then?

This question is supposed to be solved using basic high school physics like Gauss Law and fundamental properties of conductors. I would be really grateful if anyone would provide an hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is dependent on solution of another problem. You need to understand that problem first.

A hollow insulating spherical shell of radius R (negligible thickness) has charge Q distributed **non-uniformly** over it. We want to find potential at its center.

The answer is $V = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}$

The fact that charge distribution is non-uniform does not change the answer. Try to figure out why. (Take an element on surface. Find potential due to it. Integrate. Distance of center from all dQ is going to be same.)

Now come to this problem. At center there will be potential due to three reasons.

1. Charge q at distance a from center.
2. Charge $q_1$ at distance b from center.
3. Charge Q distributed over spherical shell of radius R.

This should lead you to answer directly.

Charge Q on surface of shell is going to have interesting distribution on inner side as well as outer side. However the distribution does not matter for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I will continue the train of thought that your teacher followed. Firstly, we have symmetry in this question that we can leverage on, is that the spherical shell, and the location of the potential that we need to find, has a spherical symmetry. And this will be very essential in the parts to follow.

So we first note that there are 3 different 'contributors' of charge, and by the principle of superposition (that also applies for potential), we can isolate the contribution of each charge to the centre, which we will call $V_1, V_2, V_3$

1. The charge outside the shell, $q_1$
2. The charge on the shell $Q$
3. The charge inside the shell $q$

So for the first scenario, we remove the 2nd and 3rd charge, only leaving the outer charge and the neutral spherical conducting shell. Then if we examine the potential of the conducting shell due to the 1st charge, we can via a few  ways (such as method of images) see that this is equal to $V = \frac{q_1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 b}$. But the easiest way is to see the symmetry. If we split $q_1$ to 2 separate pieces of $q_1/2$ charge, and move them around, as long as they are $b$ distance away from the centre, each of them still account for
half the potential. Then if we repeat this procedure for $ N \rightarrow \infty$, and we arrange the charges such that they form a spherical shell of $b$ radius, evidently, then we can see that $V = \frac{q_1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 b}$. From which, it follows that the potential at the centre of this configuration must be $V_1 = \frac{q_1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 b}$.

For the second scenario, we remove the 1st and 3rd charge, and by simple Gauss law and properties of conductors, then the potential at the centre of this configuration must be $V_2 = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}$.

For the third scenario, we remove the 1st and 2nd charge, and by a similar argument as in the first scenario, we can utilise the spherical symmetry, to divide this charge $q$ to $N\rightarrow\infty$ parts, and similarly arrange in a spherical shell of $a$ radius. Then, we have that $V_3 = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a}$

Hence, the final answer is the summation of all these individual contributions, $V = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}(\frac{q_1}{b} + \frac{Q}{R} + \frac{q}{a})$

Note, that this is not the only way to go about solving this question, method of images can be a really insightful way of going about this as well :)